# How to set column value with many special characters using an SQL-query in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to mass update about 150 fields in my database. I am using a WordPress WooCommerce plugin called Fixed Quantity Price, and all the products has the same price structure. The problem is that I need to update them all. This will take too much time to do manually. I have tried to learn how I can do this with an SQL-query, but I am stuck.

What I have so far is:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = "{&quot;woofix&quot;:{&quot;customer&quot;:[{&quot;woofix_desc&quot;:&quot;{qty} stk for {custom} kr&quot;,&quot;woofix_qty&quot;:125,&quot;woofix_disc&quot;:75.2,&quot;woofix_price&quot;:2.48},{&quot;woofix_desc&quot;:&quot;{qty} stk for {custom} kr&quot;,&quot;woofix_qty&quot;:250,&quot;woofix_disc&quot;:83.2,&quot;woofix_price&quot;:1.68},{&quot;woofix_desc&quot;:&quot;{qty} stk for {custom} kr&quot;,&quot;woofix_qty&quot;:500,&quot;woofix_disc&quot;:88.2,&quot;woofix_price&quot;:1.18},{&quot;woofix_desc&quot;:&quot;{qty} stk for {custom} kr&quot;,&quot;woofix_qty&quot;:1000,&quot;woofix_disc&quot;:91,&quot;woofix_price&quot;:0.9},{&quot;woofix_desc&quot;:&quot;{qty} stk for {custom} kr&quot;,&quot;woofix_qty&quot;:1500,&quot;woofix_disc&quot;:92,&quot;woofix_price&quot;:0.8},{&quot;woofix_desc&quot;:&quot;{qty} stk for {custom} kr&quot;,&quot;woofix_qty&quot;:2000,&quot;woofix_disc&quot;:93,&quot;woofix_price&quot;:0.7}]}}"
WHERE meta_key = "_woofix"
```

I get the following error:

> "#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax '"{&quot)' on line 1."

I have been able to deduce that it probably has something to do with all the special characters that are included in this "string". Is it possible to force the query to just add the literal string to the "meta_value" field? I have tried both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the delimiter from ";" to something not included in the string in the box below the SQL-field worked.